# Adding a UIView's to the Subview which is already added to the MainView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, addsubview, subviews

The structure is like this,..

> *) MainView
>
> ```
>      1) viewLocations(UIVIEW) // this one is adding fine
>
>             a) viewBangalore
>             b) viewHyderbad
> ```

Actually I'm doing a iPad App , in one of the UIViewController I've used a UiTableController as a sliding view to pick the Locations . According to locations pick ,need to display UiView's.

[image]

viewLocations --> CGRectMake(0,108,588,533)

Here My code is :

```
 if (_detailItem) {
        Location=[_detailItem description];

        if ([Location isEqual:@"Bangalore"]) {
           self.viewLocBangalore= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 500, 400)];
           // self.viewLocBangalore.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 500, 400);
            [self.viewLocations addSubview:self.viewLocBangalore];

          [UIView transitionFromView:self.viewLocHyderbad
                                toView:self.viewLocBangalore
                              duration:0.9
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom

                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                NSLog(@"Locations View Appeared %@", Location);
                            }];

        }

        else if ([Location isEqual:@"Hyderbad"])
        {
            self.viewLocHyderbad.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 600, 519);
            [self.viewLocHyderbad removeFromSuperview];
            [self.ViewLocations addSubview:self.viewLocHyderbad];

            [UIView transitionFromView:self.viewLocBangalore
                                toView:self.viewLocHyderbad
                              duration:0.9
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom

                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                NSLog(@"Locations View Appeared %@", Location); // getting this Log also, but View is missing
                            }];

        }




    }
```

I have tried so far , I din't get the solution for it . what is exactly happening here ..?
Thanks.

Comment: check with view background colors?

Comment: @Sunny I have tried with that also ..

Comment: have you made sure self.viewLocations is connected (not nil) ?

Comment: once check all the views mean those or not equal to nil.

Comment: @Sunny, Mariam N : No problem with those things .checking for every compile ..

Answer (score 1):

may be some other view overlaps that view but i'm not sure try with this method .

```
[self.ViewLocations bringSubviewToFront:viewname];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but nothing happening .