# Not updating UIView of subView?

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

I have already posted " [HERe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337056/not-triggering-event-handler-of-uibutton-from-a-method.)" .

and [Here actually What I need to Deserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318003/adding-a-uiviews-to-the-subview-which-is-already-added-to-the-mainview.)

If I put this part of code `[self loadLocationView]` in `UIButton and ViewDidLoad method` , `It works fine here.`

but whenever I choose a location from TableVeiw and calling from a `configureViewSlider` method ,  It gets called to the method `loadLocationView`  but Not updating UI.
Here I have tried so far.

```
-(void) configureViewSlider
{

    if (_detailItem) {
        Location=[_detailItem description];
        //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(btnLocations:) withObject:nil  waitUntilDone:false];
        //[btnLocations sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

      //  [self loadLocationView];
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadLocationView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        //[self loadView];
        NSLog(@"Location %@", Location);

    }
}


-(void) loadLocationView
{
    _viewLocBangalore.frame= CGRectMake(10, 10, 303,255);
    [self.view  addSubview:_viewLocBangalore];

    // [self.View bringSubviewToFront:_viewlocBangalore];
    //[_viewLocBangalore setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

What else I have to do to achieve it . I have tried in all possible ways . but No use .

Please do some suggestion at least, I'm ready to approach for any way which is ready deserve  my task (i..e.. I have added a UITableVieContrller which has locations , when user touches the Location , the UIView should update ).

Comment: Check once whether your loadLocationView method is getting called in main thread, by putting the break point.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned in the question also . Even it is getting call and printing the Log value .

Comment: ok, once try directly putting the view, without transition animation.

Comment: Could you please tell me what this means     [ViewLocations removeFromSuperview];
    self.ViewLocations=nil;    Is it affecting anywhere ?

Comment: Ok I have just followed and put only related SubView . Nothing Happening . If I call this fuction from ViewDidLoad then works fine .

Comment: I have edited in simpler way . plz check it

Answer (score 0):

Why u called  configureViewSlider method then loadlocationview method directly  location selection tableview method add this view:
 _viewLocBangalore.frame= CGRectMake(10, 10, 303,255);
    [self.view  addSubview:_viewLocBangalore];

Comment: For understanding purpose . but even still it is not working .

Comment: check the subviews NSLog(@"subView:%@",[self.view subviews]);